# VBA to save an excel sheet including its macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a macro that saves a sheet on a new workbook including the macro that are in this sheet.
But I fail, the new workbook is an macro enabled workbook, but the buttons inside are reffering to the macro that are on the original file :-(

How can I copy the macro in the new workbook ?
The macro to be copied is called "my_macro"

Below is the code I currently use that fails:

```
Sub aSaveout()

Sheets("mysheet").Select
ActiveSheet.Copy
'ThisFile = Range("A1").Value
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="mysheet.xlsm", FileFormat:=52
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` ?

Comment: Try FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

Comment: If you are talking about macro code assigned to an ActiveX button then that code should be within the worksheet's code sheet (e.g. Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)). If you copy the worksheet to a new workbook, the code sheet should come along for the ride. Just tested this and it works.

Comment: Hello.

iDevlop : I did not use ThisWorkbook.SaveAs because I wanted to save only one sheet.

Matthew : xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled is the same as Format:=52

Jeeped : for the meantime I only used macro and buttons....  ActiveX button might be the solution! I will try tomorrow

Comment: As @Jeeped mentioned: `Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Book4").Sheets(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your participation>
 Jeeped was right, activeX Control works and gets exported to the new saved file.